# How to share video on flickr

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, hyperlink

i m working an IOS app in which i needs to share a video/(or video link) on flickr .
 i search a lot but didn't get as required .

Plz provide me code or clue for doing this .

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you meant "FLICKR" then you can find Flickr ObjC SDK on Github, just search Github for Objective FLickr. Good Luck!

Comment: @fahri Azimov , ya i mean it "flickr". i have 'Flickr ObjC SDK' but didn't know how to use it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

all api documentation is available over there